# Como usar JSON no asp.net MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-5

Sou iniciante em Asp.Net MVC, e estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que gerencia **Cursos** e na minha tela de **inscrição** estou tentando fazer uma validação que caso o **aluno** já esteja **inscrito** em um curso e ele tente se inscrever **novamente nesse mesmo curso**, deve aparecer uma mensagem **Você já está inscrito nesse Curso**. A outra validação é quando a **quantidade de vagas** chegar a *zero*, o **status do curso** de deve mudar para **Encerrado** ao invés de ficar como **Curso Disponível**. Me falaram para usar **JSON** mas ainda não sei como usá-lo, alguém pode me ajudar!?

**Minha View Inscrição**

```html
@model IEnumerable<MeuProjeto.Models.Curso>

<style>
    #Status {
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .encerrado {
        background-color: green;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
        color: white;
    }

    .disponivel {
        background-color: orange;
        font-family: 'Times New Roman';
        color: white;
    }

</style>

<h2>Catálogo de Cursos</h2>

<table class="table table-hover">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Curso
        </th>
        <th>
            Sigla
        </th>
        <th>
            Ementa
        </th>
        <th>
            Inicio
        </th>
        <th>
            Fim
        </th>
        <th>
            Turno
        </th>
        <th>
            Status
        </th>
        <th>
            Quantidade de Vagas
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
           <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nome_Curso)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Sigla)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="~/Curso/Ementa?id=@item.Id">Ementa</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Inicio)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Dt_Fim)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Turno)
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Status" id="Status" value="@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Status)" readonly class="Status" />
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Qtd_Vagas)
            </td>
            <td>
               <div class="btn-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        @using (Html.BeginForm("Inscricao", "Curso", FormMethod.Post))
                        {
                            if (item.Qtd_Vagas > 0)
                             {
                                 <a class="inscricao btn btn-success" onclick="$(this).parents('form').submit(), Alerta()">Inscrição</a>
                                 <input type="hidden" value="@item.Id" name="inscricaoId" />
                             }
                            else
                            {
                                 <input type="submit" value="Não há vagas" name="detalhes" class="inscricao btn btn-default" disabled="disabled"/>
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>

    }

</table>
<div class="form-group">

    <a href="@Url.Action("HomeAluno", "Home")"><input type="button" value="Voltar" class="btn btn-danger" /></a>

</div>
<br />


@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".inscricao").click(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Inscricao/",
                    data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") },
                    success: function() {
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.Status').each(function() {
                if ($(this).val() == "Curso Disponível") {
                    $(this).addClass("disponivel");
                }
                if ($(this).val() == "Encerrado") {
                    $(this).addClass("encerrado");
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Action Inscricao** do `controller Curso`

```
public ActionResult Inscricao(string pesquisar)
    {
        Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno == null)
            return View("MeusCursos");

        var cursos = from c in db.Cursos select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisar))
        {
            cursos = cursos.Where(c => c.Nome_Curso.Contains(pesquisar));
        }
        cursos = cursos.OrderBy(a => a.Nome_Curso);

        return View(cursos.ToList());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Inscricao(int inscricaoId, string pesquisar)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
        {
            //Aqui pega o usuario logado
            Aluno aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
            if (aluno == null)
                return View("MeusCursos");

            //Aqui pega o curso selecionado
            var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == inscricaoId);
            if (curso == null)
                return View("MeusCursos");

            if (curso.Qtd_Vagas <= 0)
            {
                //TempData["MensagemErro"] = "Não existem mais vagas para este curso.";
                return RedirectToAction("Inscricao");
            }

            //Aqui verifica se o aluno já está inscrito em algum curso
            var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Curso.Id == inscricaoId && ac.Aluno.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
            if (alunoCurso != null)
            {
                //TempData["Erro"] = "Aluno já está inscrito no curso.";
                return RedirectToAction("Inscricao", "Curso");
            }

            //Aqui faz a associação do Aluno e Curso
            alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso
            {
                Aluno = aluno,
                Curso = curso
            };

            db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
            db.SaveChanges();

            //Aqui decrementa a quantidade de vagas dos Cursos
            curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
            db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();

            scope.Complete();
        }

        var cursos = from c in db.Cursos select c;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisar))
        {
            cursos = cursos.Where(c => c.Nome_Curso.Contains(pesquisar));
        }
        cursos = cursos.OrderBy(a => a.Nome_Curso);

        return View(cursos.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Pode colocar também o código do *Controller* na sua pergunta?

Comment: Editei a pergunta @CiganoMorrisonMendez, coloquei minha `action`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O código está bom. Temos apenas que enriquecer a interface.

Vamos alterar este código:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".inscricao").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Inscricao/",
                data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") },
                success: function() {
                    window.location.reload();
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

[Na documentação sobre `.ajax()` do jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), temos que a `function success` (um *callback*) tem três parâmetros:

```
success
Type: Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR )
```

O retorno de uma *Action* é preenchido em `data`, então vamos usar `data` para obter a informação que queremos. Primeiro vou alterar o JavaScript, e a alteração deve ficar mais clara quando eu explicar o código da *Action*:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".inscricao").click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Inscricao/",
                data: { inscricaoId: $(this).data("inscricaoid") },
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.Mensagem != "Ok!") {
                        alert(data.Mensagem);
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Vamos alterar agora sua *Action*:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Inscricao(int inscricaoId)
{
    using (var scope = new TransactionScope())
    {
        //Aqui pega o usuario logado
        var aluno = db.Alunos.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (aluno == null)
            return Json(new { Mensagem = "Aluno não encontrado." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        //Aqui pega o curso selecionado
        var curso = db.Cursos.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == inscricaoId);
        if (curso == null)
            return Json(new { Mensagem = "Curso não encontrado." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        if (curso.Qtd_Vagas <= 0)
        {
            //TempData["MensagemErro"] = "Não existem mais vagas para este curso.";
            return Json(new { Mensagem = "Não existem mais vagas para este curso." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        //Aqui verifica se o aluno já está inscrito em algum curso
        var alunoCurso = db.AlunoCursos.FirstOrDefault(ac => ac.Curso.Id == inscricaoId && ac.Aluno.Usuario == User.Identity.Name);
        if (alunoCurso != null)
        {
            //TempData["Erro"] = "Aluno já está inscrito no curso.";
            return Json(new { Mensagem = "Aluno já está inscrito no curso." }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        //Aqui faz a associação do Aluno e Curso
        alunoCurso = new AlunoCurso
        {
            Aluno = aluno,
            Curso = curso
        };

        db.AlunoCursos.Add(alunoCurso);
        db.SaveChanges();

        //Aqui decrementa a quantidade de vagas dos Cursos
        curso.Qtd_Vagas--;
        db.Entry(curso).State = EntityState.Modified;
        db.SaveChanges();

        scope.Complete();
    }

    var cursos = from c in db.Cursos select c;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(pesquisar))
    {
        cursos = cursos.Where(c => c.Nome_Curso.Contains(pesquisar));
    }
    cursos = cursos.OrderBy(a => a.Nome_Curso);

    return Json(new { Mensagem = "Ok!" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Repare que troquei todos os retornos como ação por JSONs. A ideia é devolver a mensagem de erro adequada para cada verificação.

Agora é adaptar o código para as suas necessidades.

Comment: Mas e quanto ao meu campo **Status** @Cigano, como eu faria para ele mudar?

Comment: @Novato Na mensagem "Não existem mais vagas para este curso", basta colocar uma regra adicional para mudar o texto de Status.

Comment: O **JSON** não retorna um `popup` não né @Cigano?

Comment: Não. Você precisa criar o Popup. Tem algumas maneiras pra isso.

Comment: como eu faria esse Popup? @Cigano

Comment: http://nakupanda.github.io/bootstrap3-dialog/